# Get divHeight in one div and, depending on the value, load a certain div or class into another div

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have two floated divs: a `#center` div and a `#sidebar` div. Center div has got updatable text in it and so its height is set to `auto`. The sidebar div also has height auto but, right underneath a scrolling div with definite height, it continues till reaching the bottom of the first div. I want to fill this different space by loading a proper class (each with different backgrounds and different heights).

So far I managed to create a js script that retrieves center div height and displays a msg according to its value.

```
<div id="center">
    <p>Some long text</p>
</div>
<div id="sidebar">
    <div class="scroller"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">

    var gd;
    function getDivHeight(divID){ 
        gd = document.getElementById('center').offsetHeight;
        if(gd <=400) alert("no space");
        else if(gd >400 <=500) alert("short space");
        else if(gd >500 <=600) alert("mid space");
        else if(gd >600 <=700) alert("large space");
        else if(gd >700) alert("too much space");
    }

    getDivHeight('center'); 
                
</script>
```

What I don't know is how can I use that gd value to load a certain class or div. Can it be done all in JS or do I need some PHP? I'm new in both of them and can't really find my way around without some help.
Any suggestion or hint that could put me on the right track will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I guess it can't be done this way since Php is parsing the page before JS is performing any kind of calculation. The only way to do such thing is probably passing through Ajax and return to php which sounds awfully complicate to me ^__^

Alberto

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, PHP runs on the server and javascript runs on the browser (client-side).  If you want new information from the server, javascript cant access the server.

The way around that is to use **AJAX** calls, where a user action such as scrolling or button press initiates a javascript function that fetches some data/information from the server.  The server can provide this using PHP (or another language).  In the browser, javascript can then insert or add this information (perhaps a div) dynamically to the existing page.

There is a very simple ajax example here (with PHP).  I am not associated with it.  I would recommend that you download and get it working to understand [AJAX](https://code-boxx.com/simple-ajax-php/).